# Safari Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

I need help in safari extension. I am porting from Chrome Extension to Safari Extension. I have used  for sending Messages to the API.
Now I am not getting how can I do the same thing for Safari Extension. I already went through Safari Messages and Proxies support. But it is not very clear how to use that.

I have three files

```
popup.html
popup.js
background.js
```

In popup.html all the HTML resides, button inputs and other html things.
In Popup.js resides methods and events like onclick of buttons. Like below text,

In Popup.js resides methods and events like onclick of buttons. Like below text,

```
function gen_generate_click(e) {


    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'name': 'get_new_generate_password'}, function(response) {
       set_password_generate( response.password );
      });
```

Here on click of button we are sending message to the background.js which contain event listener like,

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {   
   if (request.name == 'get_new_generate_password') {
    $.when( generate_password(getStorageMemory('url'), getStorageMemory('auth_key')) ).then(
    function(password) {
                sendResponse({ 'password':  password});
    }
   );
   }    
  });
```

The point here is I am not able to find a way to handle these type of requests and sending messages in safari.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: To get help with this, you need to explain a bit more about the structure of your extension. Which part is calling what with `sendMessage`?

Comment: Please help me @Xan